# Globally change UINavigationBar bar tint color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, swift3, ios10

Setting `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` used to change the `tintColor` across the entire application. On iOS 10, this is not the case anymore.

```
private func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Set tint color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black

    return true
}
```

How can I change the navigation bar tint color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. It was changed in iOS 10.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
```

Comment: @DanielStorm I think so. Otherwise no updated app would ever work again on old versions